# Matlab → R, lost in translation: why ode45 yields totally different results?

Tags: r, matlab, ode, solver, ode45

I am neither very familliar with coding nor stackoverflow, I am trying to replicate this following work: https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-0716-0191-4_12 using the data provided in the book chapter.

I do not have access to MATLAB, I tried to run the code in a trial version but there was too many errors.
Thus, I decided to go with R.

Here is my code (issue is described at the end of the post):

```r
# Loads the experimental data
library(readxl)
Data <- readxl::read_excel("exp_data.xlsx", sheet = "F1") 
Data <- data.frame(Data)

# Defines starting values from experimental data 
c0 <- c(Xv = 3.024E8, Xd = 2.01E7, Glc = 37.42, Gln = 7.59)

# Definition of model parameters 
Parameters <- c(mumax = 0.05, mudmax = 0.03, mudmin = 0.003, qGlcmax = 3E-10, qGlnmax = 8.5E-11, KsGlc = 0.03, KsGln = 0.03, KGlc = 0.19, KGln = 1) 

# Defines the model
Model <- function(t, c, Parameters) { 

# Renames

mumax <- Parameters[1] 
mudmax <- Parameters[2] 
mudmin <- Parameters[3] 
qGlcmax <- Parameters[4] 
qGlnmax <- Parameters[5] 
KsGlc <- Parameters[6] 
KsGln <- Parameters[7] 
KGlc <- Parameters[8] 
KGln <- Parameters[9] 

Xv <- c[1] # viable cell density 
Xd <- c[2] # dead cell density 
Glc <- c[3] # glucose concentration 
Gln <- c[4] # glutamine concentration 

# Representation of the kinetic relationships 

mu <- mumax*(Glc /(Glc+KsGlc))*(Gln /(Gln+KsGln)) 
mud <- mudmin + mudmax*(KsGlc/(KsGlc+Glc)) 
qglc <- qGlcmax*(Glc/(Glc+KsGlc))*(mu/(mu+mumax)+0.5) 
qgln <- qGlnmax*(Gln/(Gln+KsGln)) 

# Process model, here for batch 

dcdt <- numeric(4) 
dcdt[1] <- (mu-mud)*Xv #Xv 
dcdt[2] <- mud*Xv #Xd 
dcdt[3] <- -qglc*Xv #cglc 
dcdt[4] <- -qgln*Xv #cgln 

# Current concentration changes as output 
return(list(dcdt)) }

# Time steps to be simulated 
tspan <- 0:200 # [h] 

# Call of model function, solved for tspan 
library(deSolve) 
prior <- ode(y = c0, times = tspan, func = Model, parms = Parameters, method = "ode45") # prior gives a consistent result whith a cell growth even if the values are too low compared to experimental data

# Compares prior to experimental data, define objective function

tspan <- Data$time #experimental tspan up to 180h only 
Weighting <- c(100, 1, 10, 100)
Magnitude <- c(1E-9, 1E-8, 1, 1)   

objective <- function(Parameters, Weighting) { 
# Call of ode system 
c <- ode(func = Model, times = tspan, y = c0, parms = Parameters, method = "ode45") 
# Calculate sum of squares
Sum_of_squares <- Weighting[1]*sum((abs(c[,1]- Data[,2])*Magnitude[1])^2) + Weighting[2]*sum((abs(c[,2]-Data[,3])*Magnitude[2])^2) + Weighting[3]*sum((abs(c[,3]-Data[,4])*Magnitude[3])^2) + Weighting[4]*sum((abs(c[,4]-Data[,5])*Magnitude[4])^2) 
return(Sum_of_squares) } 

# Estimation of model parameters with Nelder-Mead algorithm 
Estimated_Parameters <- optim(par = Parameters, fn = objective, Weighting = Weighting, method = "Nelder-Mead")$par 
print(Estimated_Parameters)
```

I have to mention the following warning after runing the optim function:

```r
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)

warnings()

1: In rk(y, times, func, parms, method = "ode45", ...) :
  Number of time steps 59966 exceeded maxsteps at t = 0.000199293
2: In rk(y, times, func, parms, method = "ode45", ...) :
  Number of time steps 61726 exceeded maxsteps at t = 0.00318004
3: In rk(y, times, func, parms, method = "ode45", ...) :
  Number of time steps 59978 exceeded maxsteps at t = 0.000471839
4: In rk(y, times, func, parms, method = "ode45", ...) :
  Number of time steps 59971 exceeded maxsteps at t = 0.00039857
5: In rk(y, times, func, parms, method = "ode45", ...) :
  Number of time steps 61904 exceeded maxsteps at t = 0.0050244
...
```

As mentioned in the title, the results I get are totally different from those in the document.
While I should get the following result:

```r
3.7900e-02 4.2100e-02 2.4000e-03 6.2000e-11 4.5000e-12 4.3800e-02 3.2800e-02 4.3300e-02 1.4787e+00
```

I obtained this:

```r
7.297162e-02  1.390685e-02 -1.812314e-02  3.653943e-08 -5.175317e-02  7.573135e-02  6.733384e-02  2.190989e-01  1.033314e+00
```

I tried to increase the maxsteps to get rid of the warnings without success.

Out of curiosity, I also tried to run the simulation with the Estimated_Parameters I should get and... surprise! The simulation result is worse than the original. That's why I suspect the solver for now, but I assume a mistake with the code is more likely. Tell me if more details are needed, thanks!

Edit: experimental data table ↓

| time | Xv | Xd | glc | gln |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 302000000 | 20000000 | 37.42 | 7.59 |
| 12 | 396000000 | 25700000 | 36.81 | 7.09 |
| 24 | 621000000 | 43600000 | 34.00 | 6.40 |
| 36 | 1020000000 | 59300000 | 35.02 | 5.50 |
| 48 | 1470000000 | 100000000 | 31.73 | 4.64 |
| 60 | 2120000000 | 160000000 | 25.58 | 3.65 |
| 72 | 3520000000 | 222000000 | 23.05 | 2.49 |
| 84 | 5610000000 | 329000000 | 19.70 | 1.41 |
| 96 | 7510000000 | 503000000 | 16.81 | 0.33 |
| 108 | 10000000000 | 613000000 | 16.23 | 0.11 |
| 120 | 11300000000 | 766000000 | 12.71 | 0.09 |
| 132 | 12700000000 | 866000000 | 8.63 | 0.11 |
| 144 | 12900000000 | 1000000000 | 4.36 | 0.15 |
| 156 | 8260000000 | 6080000000 | 2.14 | 0.17 |
| 168 | 6350000000 | 8860000000 | 1.39 | 0.16 |
| 180 | 4640000000 | 9710000000 | 0.49 | 0.16 |

Comment: What's your expected `tspan` output of `0:1:200`? Atm it's `0:200`

Comment: With real-world models you will need to adapt the error tolerances. Especially the absolute tolerance should follow the typical scale of the components. Or you need to rescale between numerical data and model data so that the numerical data has a typical scale ~1. Otherwise errors in the smaller components get shadowed by the large components, allowing error accumulation towards qualitative differences. (It might turn out to be irrelevant, but this aspect of the numerical solution should be discussed and be explicitly present.)

Comment: Have you tried running the MATLAB code in Octave? That would probably be a better choice if your goal is to just get something running.

Comment: The initial simulation runs trough without problems and returns very similar results, regardless of the applied solver (from deSolve) and the tolerance setting. I would therefore assume a problem in the parameter estimation part, not the ode solver. This can be tested, if the data are provided in an easy to use and Stackoverflow compatible way.

Comment: @tpetzoldt Thank you very much, I have edited the initial post by adding the data. After having struggle a little bit more thanks to above contributions, you are right the estimation part is probably where the issue is.